Подключение к локальной mysql на мак, sqlalchemy
На mac установлен mysql, тренировался в синтаксисе при помощи DBeaver. Там есть несколько баз. Сервер в настройках mac запущен. Теперь пытаюсь к этим БД подключиться при помощи sqlalchemy прописываю строки
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql://root:mypas:@localhost:3306/namedb")
engine.connect()

print(engine)

В ответ в консоли No module named 'MySQLdb'
Полагаю проблема в драйвере, но как понять какой драйвер нужно прописать. Драйвер DBeaver установил автоматом, как узнать какой? Как вообще подключиться, может что-то не так понимаю?

pip install mysqlclient

Если не сложно, немного по подробнее что бы я понимал о чем речь.

pip install mysqlclient не помогло. Нашел еще подобную информацию pip install PyMySQL. Но теперь вылезает следующая ошибка
OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)Нашел информацию что это при попытке подключиться к несуществующей БД, но БД точно существует я могу с ней работать с помощью DBeaver

Как минимум не нужно ставить двоеточие в конце пароля, если его в пароле на самом деле нет

Блин. Представить не мог что буду тупить на такой мелочи. Тысяча благодарностей
